# The "in the following" expression

Tags: expressions

I am a physicist and while reading research articles I quite commonly find the expression "In the following", below you can find two examples:

> In the following, we will (verb) ...

or

> ... will be discussed in the following.

However this expression always sounds (reads) off to me. Somehow I cannot accept that in this cases "following" could be used as a noun, always as an adjective, and a noun - be it "chapter", "section" - should follow "the following".

But let me deepen my frustration with the topic. My mother tongue is Portuguese and I have read English books since I am 12. Whilst doing my physics master's degree I used several textbooks written by American authors, but it was only when I started my work career in optics, and started reading research articles, that I started noticing this expression (it does sound so horrible to me that I would have noticed it before).

Now, optics research in my area was - and in certain part still is - dominated by German researchers. I also live in Germany since 2010 due to that fact. I notice that my German colleagues love to use that expression, because they have the literal translation of "in the following" as "im Folgenden".

I later found that indeed in the English dictionary the use of "the following" as noun is fine, but I wonder if this is just a neologism due to the almost full century of the current scientific proliferation, as rarely do I see American or British authors using that expression.

So, to condense my question in two:

Does anyone know if this is a neologism, product of non-native speakers being forced to use English for communication?

When doing revisions of my colleagues' works I always suggest changing this expression to the adjective case. Should I just let it go, or does this actually enhance readability? I really find the expression horrible, like something is utterly missing, is this also the case with native English speakers?

PS: I did find this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80436/is-in-following-acceptable-in-place-of-in-the-following) which does partly answers my questions, regarding dialects, but which in the examples never uses "following" as noun. Also [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6577/the-usage-of-following) which in the examples does not use "in the following", but simply "the following:" followed by an enumeration, which is totally fine by me, and also something I would use, because I see it as a *special kind of adjective?* Like, it gives a quality to each following item, or the enumeration, which is not the same kind of quality I see in "in the following."

I am really sorry for the long rambling.

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect English. No, it's not a neologism, but a small mistake of non-native speakers. Swap *in the following* for **below** and be done with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting a sentence with "In the following, ..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142107/starting-a-sentence-with-in-the-following)

Comment: A simple matter of checking in a reliable dictionary (which will pronounce on idiomaticity and flag for any hint of unacceptability). [Webster’s New World College Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/the-following) << Definition of **the following**
[in American English]: 1.  the one or ones to be mentioned immediately // 
2.  what follows >> and an example from [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/following_1) << Please read the following carefully. >>

Comment: @niamulbengali I had seen that post, but it did not answer if it was a neologism. Like I said, I had checked dictionaries (can't find the entry now) which, if I remember correctly, said it is allowed. But on the examples from Edwin Ashworth, I cannot see "in the following" as I outlined being a correct usage of the expression.